# What would be the time complexity for this naive method finding n prime numbers?

Tags: ruby, algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, primes

```
class Primes
  def initialize
    @primes = []
  end

  def prime_iterative(n)
    i = 2
    while @primes.size < n do
      @primes << i if is_prime?(i)
      i += 1
    end
    @primes
  end
  
  def is_prime?(n)
    @primes.each { |prime| return false if n % prime == 0 }
    true
  end
end

primes = Primes. new
puts primes.prime_iterative 10
```

its finding n prime numbers not all primes less than n. I cant determine the upper bound

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So this is trial division by primes, which is less efficient than the Sieve of Eratosthenes.

It checks the divisibility of each pair of primes, so certainly it is Ω(n²).

It's also O(n² log n), since the nth prime is (1 + o(1)) n log n, and pessimistically we divide each of the numbers up to the nth prime by each of the first n primes.

We can tighten this analysis to O(n²) (hence Θ(n²)) by observing that every composite c has a prime factor ≤ √c, so the primes take O(n²) time as noted above, and the composites take only O(n log n √(n/log n)) since each has a prime factor ≤ O(√(n log n)), which implies that we check O(√(n log n)/log √(n log n)) = O(√(n/log n)) primes.